# Javascript - call function 2 inside function 1, then proceed

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible? How to do this? When clicking on a button, I call `function1`. If the condition is true (`i==1`), the `function1` pauses and the following code will only be executed after `function2` is totally executed. Example:

```
function1(i){
    //some code here
    if(i == 1){
        function2(i);  // call function2 and waits the return to continue
    }
    //the following code
}

function2(i){
    //do something here and returns
}
```

Comment: so you think javascript is non-deterministic... ???

Comment: The call of function2 from function1 is synchronous : it "waits" until function2 is finished. You have nothing special to do.

Comment: Probably exposed to AJAX too early and it ruined their perception of programming.

Comment: You could try with a simple alert inside function2() , then an alert after the call to function2() has been made from function1() to see what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function1(i){
    //some code here
    if(i == 1){
        function2(i);  // call function2 and waits the return to continue
    }
    //the following code
}

function2(i){
    //do something here and returns
}
```

In case you meant that `function2` is actually async in some manner:

```
function1(i){
    //some code here
    if(i == 1){
        // call function2 and waits for return to continue
        function2(i, function() {
            // the following code
        });  
    }
    else {
        //the following code
    }
}

function2(i, callback){
    //do something async here and return when complete
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}
```

Comment: hee hee, that is funny!  But, i think this person is doing async and does not know it? if that is the case may I suggest adding a callback parameter

Comment: There is nothing async about their code... but I added an async example just in case.

Comment: Works perfectly! The only problem is that I dont want to duplicate "the following code", but I know how to void this. Thanks for your supporting!

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you find an answer helpful please make sure to upvote it and mark it as the answer. This way other people will know you've been helped and can the answer easier if they have a similar question.

Comment: As I'm newer here, I'm still half-lost, but this site has been very helpful for me lately.

Comment: It's pretty simple - ask your question, figure out the answer that helped you the most and then click the up triangle and checkmark next to the answer :)